# How to correctly use pivot to create custom column names

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe with several values for a factor ordered by a date like:

```
    date_and_time           date        hour    factor st0  st1     st2
0   2012-01-01 00:00:00     2012-01-01  0       PM25    69.4000     58.00000    51.60000
1   2012-01-01 00:00:00     2012-01-01  0       CO      1.3800      1.15714     1.06585
2   2012-01-01 01:00:00     2012-01-01  1       PM25    127.2000    77.33330    89.20000
3   2012-01-01 01:00:00     2012-01-01  1       CO      1.5800      1.57143     1.63169
```

How would I get:

```
    date_and_time           date        hour    PM25_st0  PM25_st1  PM25_st2 COst0  COst1   COst2
0   2012-01-01 00:00:00     2012-01-01  0       69.4000   58.0000   51.6000  1.3800 1.15714 1.06585
1   2012-01-01 01:00:00     2012-01-01  1       127.200   77.3333   89.2000  1.5800 1.57143 1.63169
```

basically pivoting and creating corresponding columns, first I was trying this:

```
df_data = {
    'date_and_time': ['2012-01-01 00:00:00','2012-01-01 00:00:00','2012-01-01 01:00:00','2012-01-01 01:00:00' ],
    'date': ['2012-01-01','2012-01-01','2012-01-01','2012-01-01'],
    'hour':[0,0,1,1],
    'factor':['PM25','CO','PM25','CO'],
    'st0':[69.4000 ,1.3800,127.2000,1.5800],
    'st1':[58.00000,1.15714,77.33330,1.57143],
    'st2':[51.60000,1.06585,89.20000,1.63169]
}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(df_data, columns = ['date_and_time', 'date','hour','factor','st0','st1','st2'])



df_pivoted = pd.pivot_table(df_test,index=["date_and_time","date","hour"],columns=["factor"],values=["st0","st1","st2"])
```

and getting:

[image]

Is there a way to customize the column by factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) by second level of `MultiIndex in columns`, then list comprehension with `f-string`s with swapped levels and last [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex in index`:

```
df_pivoted = df_pivoted.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df_pivoted.columns = [f'{b}_{a}' for a, b in df_pivoted.columns]
df_pivoted = df_pivoted.reset_index()
print (df_pivoted)
         date_and_time        date  hour  CO_st0   CO_st1   CO_st2  PM25_st0  \
0  2012-01-01 00:00:00  2012-01-01     0    1.38  1.15714  1.06585      69.4   
1  2012-01-01 01:00:00  2012-01-01     1    1.58  1.57143  1.63169     127.2   

   PM25_st1  PM25_st2  
0   58.0000      51.6  
1   77.3333      89.2
```